# How to determine if an Android device has an Accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want to check if an Android device has an accelerometer or not so that I can put a toast message saying that the game won't work properly on the current device if there isn't an accelerometer. I am looking for something like this:

```
if(DEVICE_HAS_ACCELEROMETER == false){
Toast.makeText(context,"No Accelerometer Found.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If you can fill in the DEVICE_HAS_ACCELEROMETER part, that would do the job.

PS: I am not in an activity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (accelerometerSensor != null)
{
    // Device has Accelerometer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean accelerometer;

accelerometer = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

if(accelerometer) 
{
.
.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The method "sManager.registerListener(SensorListener listener, int sensors)" is deprecated. And when we give "this" as a parameter I get the error: The method registerListener(SensorListener, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (GameView, Sensor)

Answer (score 3):

Do something like the following ,

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> s=sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
 for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
   {
        Sensor tmp = s.get(i);
        if (tmp.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        DEVICE_HAS_ACCELEROMETER=true;
         else
        DEVICE_HAS_ACCELEROMETER=false;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 SensorManager Sensors = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 Sensor mAccelerometer = Sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

mAccelerometer will have the accelerometre val.

[From here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
accelerometer = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

if(accelerometer) 
{

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The method "sManager.registerListener(SensorListener listener, int sensors)" is deprecated. And when we give "this" as a parameter I get the error: The method registerListener(SensorListener, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (GameView, Sensor)

Answer (score 0):

```
SensorManager sManager;
acce = sManager.registerListener(this,sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

if(acce) 
{

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The method "sManager.registerListener(SensorListener listener, int sensors)" is deprecated. And when we give "this" as a parameter I get the error: The method registerListener(SensorListener, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (GameView, Sensor)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it via PackageManger in one line.

```
boolean isAccSupported = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);
```